# How to apply function over each matrix element's indices

Tags: r, function, dictionary, matrix, apply

I am wondering if there is a built-in function in R which applies a function to each element of the matrix (of course, the function should be computed based on matrix indices). The equivalent would be something like this:

```
matrix_apply <- function(m, f) {
  m2 <- m
  for (r in seq(nrow(m2)))
    for (c in seq(ncol(m2)))
      m2[[r, c]] <- f(r, c)
  return(m2)
}
```

If there is no such built-in function, what is the best way to initialize a matrix to contain values obtained by computing an arbitrary function which has matrix indices as parameters?

Comment: are you familiar with the aptly named `apply()` family of functions? The MARGIN parameter accepts values for rows, columns, and rows & columns. Not to mention that quite a few R functions are vectorized and can avoid this type of programming.

Comment: @leden can you give an example of `f()`? As far as I can tell, any vectorized function will work on a matrix as it is just a vector with a dim attribute. You don't need to break it down into row and columns indices. At the moment there is an amount of ambiguity in your Q; it seems like you want a general solution but proscribe that it should b based on indices, which is sub-optimal.

Comment: What I mean is, why can't `f()` be written such that all you really need is `m[] <- f(m)`? I'll add an example...

Comment: I think the OP needs to respond to all of us, and not just because it's polite :-) .

Reading his example exactly as written,  is m2 matrix is generated with a function
'f(r,c)' which is purely a function of the indices and has nothing to do  with the contents of the original matrix.   Since that's presumably not what he wanted, as opposed to 'g(r,c,m[r,c])' , or 'g(m[r,c])' , the answers provided so far are very good but not necessarily answering his (ambiguous) question.

Comment: I just need to be able to apply a function which takes at least indices of each matrix columns. One such application, is let's say I want to create a multiplication table, or just evaluate some function of two parameters and store the results into the matrix.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I suspect you want `outer`:

```
> mat <- matrix(NA, nrow=5, ncol=3)

> outer(1:nrow(mat), 1:ncol(mat) , FUN="*")
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    4    6
[3,]    3    6    9
[4,]    4    8   12
[5,]    5   10   15

> outer(1:nrow(mat), 1:ncol(mat) , FUN=function(r,c) log(r+c) )
          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 0.6931472 1.098612 1.386294
[2,] 1.0986123 1.386294 1.609438
[3,] 1.3862944 1.609438 1.791759
[4,] 1.6094379 1.791759 1.945910
[5,] 1.7917595 1.945910 2.079442
```

That yields a nice compact output. but it's possible that `mapply` would be useful in other situations. It is helpful to think of `mapply` as just another way to do the same operation that others on this page are using `Vectorize` for. `mapply` is more general because of the inability `Vectorize` to use  "primitive" functions.

```
data.frame(mrow=c(row(mat)),   # straightens out the arguments
           mcol=c(col(mat)), 
           m.f.res= mapply(function(r,c) log(r+c), row(mat), col(mat)  ) )
#   mrow mcol   m.f.res
1     1    1 0.6931472
2     2    1 1.0986123
3     3    1 1.3862944
4     4    1 1.6094379
5     5    1 1.7917595
6     1    2 1.0986123
7     2    2 1.3862944
8     3    2 1.6094379
9     4    2 1.7917595
10    5    2 1.9459101
11    1    3 1.3862944
12    2    3 1.6094379
13    3    3 1.7917595
14    4    3 1.9459101
15    5    3 2.0794415
```

You probably didn't really mean to supply to the function what the row() and col() functions would have returned: This produces an array of 15 (somewhat redundant) 3 x 5 matrices:

```
> outer(row(mat), col(mat) , FUN=function(r,c) log(r+c) )
```

Answer (score 19):

The simplest approach *is* just to use an `f()` that can be applied directly to the elements of the matrix. For example, using the matrix `m` from @adamleerich's Answer

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow = 2)
```

There is no reason to use `apply()` in the case of the `as.character()` example. Instead we can operate on the elements of `m` as if it were a vector (it *really* is one) and replace *in-place*:

```
> m[] <- as.character(m)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "1"  "3"  "5"  "7" 
[2,] "2"  "4"  "6"  "8"
```

The first part of that block is the key here. `m[]` forces the elements of `m` to be replaced by the output from `as.character()`, rather than overwriting `m` with a vector of characters.

So that *is* the general solution to applying a function to each element of a matrix.

If one really needs to use an `f()` that works on row and column indices then I'd write a `f()` using `row()` and `col()`:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow = 2)
> row(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2    2    2
> col(m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    1    2    3    4
> row(m) * col(m) ## `*`(row(m), col(m)) to see this is just f()
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3    4
[2,]    2    4    6    8
```

or one that use `outer()` as other's have shown. If `f()` isn't vectorised, then I'd rethink my strategy as far as possible as there i) probably is a way to write a truly vectorised version, and ii) a function that isn't vectorised isn't going to scale very well.

Answer (score 14):

You didn't tell us what kind of function you want to apply to each element, but I think that the only reason the examples in the other answers work is because the functions are already vectorized.  If you really want to apply a function to each element, `outer` will not give you anything special that the function didn't already give you.  You'll notice that the answers didn't even pass a matrix to `outer`!

How about following @Chase's comment and use `apply`.

For example, I have the matrix

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), nrow = 2)
```

If I want to turn it into a character matrix, element by element (just as an example) I could do this

```
apply(m, c(1,2), as.character)
```

Of course, `as.character` is already vectorized, but my special function `my.special.function` isn't.  It only takes one argument, an element.  There is no straighforward way to get `outer` to work with it.  But, this works

```
apply(m, c(1,2), my.special.function)
```

Comment: You can make `outer` work with a non-vectorized function, but only by faking the vectorisation in the same way you are faking it with `apply()`.

Comment: Furthermore, I show in my Answer how you can do the `as.character()` without resorting to `apply()`, and as such, we should probably be advocating the right way to do things rather than faking the desired result - your `apply()` *is* just hiding a longer single-loop where the OP had two loops nested.

Answer (score 9):

You may be thinking of `outer`:

```
rows <- 1:10
cols <- 1:10

outer(rows,cols,"+")

      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11
 [2,]    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    12
 [3,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12    13
 [4,]    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13    14
 [5,]    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14    15
 [6,]    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15    16
 [7,]    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16    17
 [8,]    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17    18
 [9,]   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18    19
[10,]   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19    20
```

That's clearly a fairly trivial example function, but you can supply your own custom one as well. See `?outer`.

*Edit*

Contrary to the comment below, you can also use `outer` with non-vectorized functions by....vectorizing them!

```
m <- matrix(1:16,4,4)

#A non-vectorized function 
myFun <- function(x,y,M){
     M[x,y] + (x*y)
}

#Oh noes! 
outer(1:4,1:4,myFun,m)
Error in dim(robj) <- c(dX, dY) : 
  dims [product 16] do not match the length of object [256]

#Oh ho! Vectorize()! 
myVecFun <- Vectorize(myFun,vectorize.args = c('x','y'))

#Voila! 
outer(1:4,1:4,myVecFun,m)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    7   12   17
[2,]    4   10   16   22
[3,]    6   13   20   27
[4,]    8   16   24   32
```

Comment: I don't think that `outer` is what he is looking for.  Just because his example with the double for loop looks like a call to `outer` doesn't mean that `outer` will work.  Can you give an example that uses a function that is not vectorized?

Comment: @adamleerich See my edit. Non-vectorized functions can be vectorized.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question exactly, but I found it while trying to figure out a similar question so I'll show you something.

Say you have a function which you want to apply to each element of a matrix which requires just one part.

```
mydouble <- function(x) {
   return(x+x)
}
```

And say you have a matrix X,

```
> x=c(1,-2,-3,4)
> X=matrix(x,2,2)
> X
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -3
[2,]   -2    4
```

then you do this:

```
res=mydouble(X)
```

Then it will do an element-wise double of each value.

However, if you do logic in the function like below you will get a warning that it is not parameterized and not behave as you expect.

```
myabs <- function(x) {
  if (x<0) {
      return (-x)
  } else {
      return (x)
  }
}

> myabs(X)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1   -3
[2,]   -2    4
Warning message:
In if (x < 0) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

But if you use the apply() function you can use it.

For example:

```
> apply(X,c(1,2),myabs)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4
```

So that is great, right?  Well, it breaks down if you have a function with two or more parms.  Say for example you have this:

```
mymath <- function(x,y) {
    if(x<0) {
        return(-x*y)
    } else {
        return(x*y)
    }
}
```

In this case, you use the apply() function.  However, it will lose the matrix but the results are calculated correctly.  They can be reformed if you are so inclined.

```
> mapply(mymath,X,X)
[1]  1 -4 -9 16
> mapply(mymath,X,2)
[1] 2 4 6 8
> matrix(mapply(mymath,X,2),c(2,2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    6
[2,]    4    8
```