# Association matrix in r

Tags: r, associations, correlation, categorical-data, r-corrplot

The way corrplot allows you to plot a correlation matrix in R

Any idea how i can plot a association matrix in R 
where the method of association is using any user specified method like Cramer's V

Comment: Did you try `corrplot` with  `is.corr=FALSE` ?

Answer (score 4):

Building upon the example by Alexey Knorre:

```
library(DescTools)
library(corrplot)

# Simulate data
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x2 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x3 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE))

# Use CramerV as input for corrplot
corrplot::corrplot(DescTools::PairApply(df, DescTools::CramerV))
```

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question strongly depends on the data you've got and specific correlation method. I assume you have a bunch of nominal variables and want to see whether they are correlated using Cramer's V on the correlation plot. In this case, a way to do this is following:

1. Calculate Cramer's V correlation coefficient for every pair of
   variables.I used `vcd` library, as it has method to calculate Cramer's V.
2. Put these coefficients together and basically get correlation matrix
3. Visualize the matrix

Ugly but working code to do this is listed below. I played around [outer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395397/how-to-apply-function-over-each-matrix-elements-indices) - the clearest and most precise way to work with row and column indexes, but encountered problems with indexing columns in `df` using row and column index from `m`: for some reason it just didn't want to get variable from df.

```
install.packages("vcd")
library(vcd)

# Simulate some data or paste your own
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x2 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x3 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE))

# Initialize empty matrix to store coefficients
empty_m <- matrix(ncol = length(df),
            nrow = length(df),
            dimnames = list(names(df), 
                            names(df)))
# Function that accepts matrix for coefficients and data and returns a correlation matrix
calculate_cramer <- function(m, df) {
 for (r in seq(nrow(m))){
   for (c in seq(ncol(m))){
     m[[r, c]] <- assocstats(table(df[[r]], df[[c]]))$cramer
   }
 }
    return(m)
}

cor_matrix <- calculate_cramer(empty_m ,data)

corrplot(cor_matrix)
```

[image: corrplot for cramer's V]

Answer (score 1):

```
library(vcd)
library(corrplot)
```

I would suggest `corrplot(PairApply(df, cramerV),diag = F,is.corr = F)` to change color scale from -1,1 (is.corr = T) to 0,1 (is.corr = F).