# corrplot: how do not show Cramer's V corr coeff for some variables

Tags: r, correlation, r-corrplot

I am plotting Cramer's V correlation coefficient using corrplot as was described before

[Association matrix in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070853/association-matrix-in-r)

```
library(DescTools)
library(corrplot)

# Simulate data
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x2 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x3 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE))

# Use CramerV as input for corrplot
corrplot::corrplot(DescTools::PairApply(df, DescTools::CramerV))
```

Is there any way to exclude the correlation coefficient for some of the variables? I would not like to show some very low coefficients...

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set those entries to zero.  For example,

```r
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x1 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x2 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 x3 = sample(letters[1:5], 20, replace = TRUE))

# Use CramerV as input for corrplot
m <- DescTools::PairApply(df, DescTools::CramerV)
m
#>           x1        x2        x3
#> x1 1.0000000 0.4699291 0.5500947
#> x2 0.4699291 1.0000000 0.5368374
#> x3 0.5500947 0.5368374 1.0000000
m[m < 0.5] <- 0
corrplot::corrplot(m)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I need! One last question: Can I somehow highlight some very high coefficients in bold?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that I use corrplot.mixed () to show both circles and coeffs. I meant, whether there is a way to highlight in bold some of these coefficients?