# Is there general method for avoiding for-loops in R in transforming a matrix?

Tags: r

I have a matrix that I would like to transform entry by entry using some general function, say `func`, that uses row and column indices as arguments. Using for-loop I would write the code as follows.

```
for(i in 1:nrow(M)){
for(j in 1:ncol(M)){
   M[i,j] <- func(i,j)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this without using loops? There have been numerous questions here in SE about avoiding loops but all of them deal with a specific way to transform a matrix. I am looking for a general method for any desired transformation, if that exists.

Comment: It depends completely on your `func`. Many functions in R are vectorised meaning you don't need to pass them one by one, you can directly do `func(M)` for them. For example, `sqrt(1:10)`. For complicated functions which cannot be vectorised you have to use a loop. It can be an explicit `for` loop or use one of the `apply` family of functions.

Comment: Have you looked at `apply()` like functions? (`lapply()`, `apply()`, *etc.*)

Comment: There is also `outer()` function as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7395664/10264278)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply function over each matrix element's indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395397/how-to-apply-function-over-each-matrix-elements-indices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer(1:nrow(M), 1:ncol(M), func)` provides a simple solution, as Paul suggests.

An more involved, and possibly more flexible, alternative is to use `vapply()`:

```
func <- function (i, j) i + j
M <- matrix(NA, 3, 5)
M <- vapply(1:ncol(M), function (j) 
       vapply(1:nrow(M),
         function (i) func(i, j),
         double(1)
       ), double(nrow(M)))
```

The `double(n)` tells `vapply()` what format the output should take, so may need modifying to e.g. `character(n)` if `func` returns a character vector.

More concisely (and more opaquely?), this can be simplified to:

```
M <- vapply(1:ncol(M), function (j) vapply(1:nrow(M), func, 0, j), double(nrow(M)))
```

And to safely handle possible cases where `M` has zero rows or columns, it's best practice to replace `1:N` with `seq_len(N)`.